# Checked List Box Item Check Event Strange Behavior

Tags: c#, checkedlistbox

```
private void checkedListBox1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
    if (checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(i) == false) 
    {
        ...
    }
    else
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

For some reason when the code above executes, it does the opposite of what I'd like it to do. When an item is checked for the first time it doesn't do anything, however, when it is unchecked it does what's in the else statement (again, opposite of what it's supposed to do). Is there some property that I'm forgetting about here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `e.NewValue` instead of `checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(i)`. The reason being that `checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked` is a *cached* state, because the `ItemCheck` event occurs **before** the internal value is updated.

This'll work as you are expecting:

```
private void checkedListBox1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NewValue == CheckState.Checked) 
    {
        ...
    }
    else
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

---

Secondly, as to why the first time you click the checkbox, it doesn't react: that's because the `CheckedListBox` object **requires** the item to be highlighted *before* changing the checkbox value through mouse clicks.

In order to achieve a *similar* effect, set `checkedListBox1.CheckOnClick = true`. This will cause the checkbox to become checked whenever clicking on the checkbox **or on** the list item itself.

Comment: Thank you, my code works just as expected now.

Answer (score 0):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.itemcheck.aspx) indicates that the check state isn't updated in the ItemCheck event until after it finishes. You're probably looking for [e.NewValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.itemcheckeventargs.aspx).